# Is Netty Sharable Channel Handler a Singleton instance?

Tags: netty, vert.x, rx-netty

Is Netty Sharable Channel Handler a Singleton instance?
I have a very high qps system system. So If I want to avoid creating handler object on every connection/request. What is the best way to achieve it?

1. @Sharable on top of handler class
2. `HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass(); pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);` 
   OR
3. creating a new handler instance is the ideal way.
   `pipeline.addLast("handler", new HandlerClass());`

Also can I create only one instance of new HttpRequestDecoder(), new HttpResponseEncoder(), new HttpObjectAggregator(65536) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if a handler is `@Sharable` it may be a singleton. That said some handlers may need some state which is per `Channel` and so can't be sharable. Also note that handlers that are `@Sharable` need to be thread-safe as different `Channel`s may use different `EventLoop`s.

Because of the "limitations" mention above not all handlers can be sharable. for example all the handlers that you listed (`HttpRequestDecoder`, `HttpResponseEncoder` and `HttpObjectAggregator`) or not sharable and so a new instance needs to be created per `Channel`.

Comment: So creating new object of HttpRequestDecoder, HttpResponseDecoder and HttpObjectAggregator on each http request will result in memory overhead and will trigger gc soon right?

Comment: I want to create very minimal objects as possible and share as much objects as possible

Comment: its per channel and so per connection. Usually a connection should handle more then one request / response.